# XQuery: Returning the highest value after ordering

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I'm still new to XQuery, but I've almost figured out this query, but it needs to just return the proteinID and the numberOfAuthors of the element with the most authors, however it's currently returning all of them instead of just the element with the highest number of authors.

My query is

```
for $i in doc("test.xml")/ProteinDatabase/ProteinEntry
let $author-count := count($i/reference/refinfo/authors)
let $proteinID := $i/@id
where $author-count = max($author-count)
order by $author-count descending
return ((<proteinID>{data($proteinID)}</proteinID>,
<numberOfAuthors>{data($author-count)}</numberOfAuthors>))
```

which returns:

```
<proteinID>QRHUA4</proteinID>
<numberOfAuthors>47</numberOfAuthors>
<proteinID>PLHU</proteinID>
<numberOfAuthors>29</numberOfAuthors>
<proteinID>LPHUB</proteinID>
<numberOfAuthors>29</numberOfAuthors>
```

and so on.

What I just want to return is the first proteinID and the highest  which is 47, like below:

```
<proteinID>QRHUA4</proteinID>
<numberOfAuthors>47</numberOfAuthors>
```

I've tried a few things, like my where statement that's in there

```
where $author-count = max($author-count)
```

but it doesn't seem to have actually done anything. I've also tried some positional things and selecting only the first index, but it seems to only return the ID QRHUA4, but not the numberOfAuthors

Comment: Please post some sample xml

Comment: sure sorry, its just quite long so i omitted it

Comment: minimal sample will do

Comment: updated the OP with an example

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can simply select the first item in the result sequence using either

```
(for $i in doc("proteindb.xml")/ProteinDatabase/ProteinEntry
let $author-count := count($i/reference/refinfo/authors)
let $proteinID := $i/@id
where $author-count = max($author-count)
order by $author-count descending
return ((<proteinID>{data($proteinID)}</proteinID>,
<numberOfAuthors>{data($author-count)}</numberOfAuthors>)))[1]
```

or

```
head(for $i in doc("proteindb.xml")/ProteinDatabase/ProteinEntry
let $author-count := count($i/reference/refinfo/authors)
let $proteinID := $i/@id
where $author-count = max($author-count)
order by $author-count descending
return ((<proteinID>{data($proteinID)}</proteinID>,
<numberOfAuthors>{data($author-count)}</numberOfAuthors>)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: For your first solution, is it possible to select two positions? Because [1] will return the proteinID, but not the associated numberOfAuthors, because that's in position [2]. I need to return both position [1] and [2] if possible

Comment: @BenWhitely, sorry, I didn't notice you return a sequence of which you need two items but there is `subsequence(for... return ..., 1, 2)` for instance or of course `(...)[position() = (1, 2)]`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried just doing [1,2] (like your first query, replacing [1] with [1,2]) to get the first and second values since that made sense to me, but I just get an "effective boolean value not defined for (1,2)" error. These are some of my first XQuery queries so I'm clearly missing something obvious

Comment: My previous comment has two suggestions, try them.

Comment: @BenWhitely, just to elaborate, a predicate (i.e. expression in square brackets) that contains solely an integer number (like `[1]`) is a positional predicate and a shortform for `[position() = 1]`. If you want to have include several positions then there is not shortform, instead you have to spell out `[position() = 1 or position() = 2]` which can also be written as `[position() = (1,2)]`. Or use the `subsequence` function which takes the sequence as the first argument, the start position as the second argument and the number of items as the third: `subsequence(for .. return .., 1, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for $i in //ProteinEntry[reference/refinfo/authors/count(*) = 
                         max(//ProteinEntry/reference/refinfo/authors/count(*))
                        ]
let $author-count := count($i/reference/refinfo/authors/author)
let $proteinID := $i/@id
return ((<proteinID>{$proteinID}</proteinID>,
<numberOfAuthors>{$author-count}</numberOfAuthors>))
```

fiddle: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9Xv4/1